# Issue with simple division in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, integer-division

I must be a total idiot or something. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008. I can't do simple division. SELECT 200/600 returns a big fat goose egg (0.00). Yet if I do 600/200 it returns 3. The only thing I can think of is some server setting. I'm feeling pretty darn stupid here. Can somebody please help?

[image: Shown on my server]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers you are using are being interpreted as integers, hence values you might not normally expect.

Try this...

```
select 200.0/600.0
```

and you'll see that SQL Server treats the numbers as floats and therefore gives you the result you want.

Alternatively you could try

```
select cast (200 as float) / cast (600 as float)
```

And you'd get the same result - all I've done here is to explicitly cast the values as floats.

Comment: That did it! Thanks much!